# Notifying member list for new topic in forum

Tags: templates, email, forum, admin

Is there any way to change the recipients of the 'Admin Notification of New Entries' email template without making all the recipients admins?

Answer (score 0):

I see one possibility, but I'm not 100% sure if this will work. If you wrote an extension that fired on this hook:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/email/index.html

You could possibly look for a conditional subject. I'm not sure what the default admin notification subject is, but if it's always the same, you could detect Admin notifications. Something like:

```
if ($data['subject'] == "Admin Notificaiton from your EE site") {

    // add to recipients string
    $data['recipients'] .= ", another@email.com, another@email.com";
}
```

The problem is that I don't necessarily know if the admin communications uses the standard Email class; I can't imagine it wouldn't, but don't have time right now to dig through the core to check for you. Good luck!